# I am having issue in javascript filteration, I am not getting the filtered items in browser but it works perfect when I console the filterd products?

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner in javascript and doing tasks for learning purpose, I am trying to filter items through javascript array filter method but the problem is that whenever I click any specific category button, It returns all the items (Not only filtered Items) in web browser, But if I try to console the filtered items then it works perfect and returns the filtered items in console (After clicking specific category it returns all items that are in that specific category), Can anyone plz point out the issue ? I would really be thankful to you :)
Below is my code js :

```
const menu = [{
                id: 1,
                title: "Our First Title",
                category: "love",
                price: 20,
                img: "cup-of-coffee-1280537_640.jpg",
                desc: `This is the short description for teting purpose... This is for first item...!`,

            },

            {
                id: 2,
                title: "Our Second Title",
                category: "love",
                price: 25,
                img: "apple-1868496_640.jpg",
                desc: `This is the short description for teting purpose... This is for Second item...!`,

            },

            {
                id: 3,
                title: "Our Third Title",
                category: "hate",
                price: 50,
                img: "desk-593327_640.jpg",
                desc: `This is the short description for teting purpose... This is for Third item...!`,

            },

        ];





        let filterButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.filterbtn');

        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Loading Items 

            filterButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
                // console.log(btn);
                btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    let category = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
                    // console.log(category);
                    let menuCategory = menu.filter(function(filters) {
                        if (filters.category === category) {
                            console.log(filters);
                            return filters;
                        }


                    });

                    

                     if (category === 'all') {
                         displayItems(menu);
                         // console.log(category);
                     } else {
                         displayItems(menuCategory);
                     }
                });
            });

            
            function displayItems() {
                let displayMap = menu.map(function(menuItems) {
                    
                    return ` <article class="menu-item">
                <img src="${menuItems.img}" class="photo" alt="menu item">


                <div class="item-info">
                    <header>
                        <h4>${menuItems.title}</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">${menuItems.price}</h4>
                    </header>
                    <p class="item-text">
                        ${menuItems.desc}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article> `;
                });
                let sectionCenter = document.querySelector('.section-center');
                displayMap = displayMap.join("");
                sectionCenter.innerHTML = displayMap;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `displayItems(menu)` and `displayItems(menuCategory)`, but your actual method doesn't expect any arguments and you iterate through the original menu array.

```
function displayItems() {
  let displayMap = menu.map(function(menuItems) {...}
}
```

If you pass the filtered array, you should use that instead, something like this:

```
function displayItems(filtered) {
  let displayMap = filtered.map(function(menuItems) {...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man ! Yes the issue is solved now as I passed a parameter !

Answer (score 0):

The `displayItems` function is rendering every element in the menu array (look at the `.map`). You are passing the filtered array as a parameter, but the function is not using any.

```js
            function displayItems(array) {
                let displayMap = array.map(function(menuItems) {
                    // etc
```

Comment: Thanks Man ! Yes the issue is solved now as I passed a parameter !